# Unable to install Tidyverse Package in RStudio

Tags: installation, packages, r, rstudio

When i try to install Tidyverse package in RStudio im geetting following error and installation gets terminated.

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:

cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

Warning in install.packages :

*package ‘tidyverse’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)*

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that your network setup doesn't like https. Try http instead.

```r
options(repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether this will help you or not, but try this:

install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, type="source", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")

Comment: Can you explain why could it help? And you can format code like using backticks